# android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED not working with nexus 4

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to use android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED for starting my service at start but I am not receiving its broadcast in nexus 4. Its working fine with Samsung phones.

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also I have given permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Receiver file:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "boot completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Boot Completed", "Boot completed received");
    }
}
```

I am not receiving BOOT_COMPLETED intent.

ITS WORKING FINE WITH SAMSUNG MODELS BUT NOT WORKING WITH NEXUS 4.
I AM USING ANDROID STUDIO.
PLEASE HELP.

Comment: You're missing `>` from the end of your first receiver tag

Comment: its not exact code buddy. Its actually there. Same apk is working with samsung but not with nexus 4

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, in my `onReceive`

```
   String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yeah. It worked for me also now. Actually, in nexus 4 it was taking a lot of time in receiving BOOT_COMPLETED but in Samsung it was very instant. So I Could not find out what was going. Anyway thanks all. :)

Comment: can you please help me in this too. You will be highly appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201891/how-to-know-which-music-player-is-currently-playing-the-song-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You will be only receiving BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast if user runs your app at least once. This is a security measure since Android 3.1.

This does not affect system applications, but I suppose you are not writing one...

Does that help?

Comment: thanks for suggestion but it worked without making activity. I just made a service and started it on receiving BOOT_COMPLETED. I did not need activity for this for first time execution.Actually it was having significant delay on nexus 4 device so I was confused whats happening. But its resolved now. :)

Comment: yes ... that is actually the case with some set of devices. We've been having reports of a long BOOT_COMPLETED delay for LG devices also.